# MS-Word run macro on doubleclick

Tags: vba, ms-word

Is there a way, how to run macro in MS word after mouse-doubleclick (outside Active-X object)?

something like `Document_DblClick(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)`

Comment: You'd need to install your own subclass or hook. There's [an example here for mousewheel events](http://www.xtremevbtalk.com/excel/325689-mousewheel-events-vba-combobox.html) - it would be the same concept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Word has an application-level event for executing VBA code (or VSTO code) when the user double-clicks on a document: WindowBeforeDoubleClick

The event provides as a parameter a Selection object, where the double-click occurred and also provides a Cancel parameter that optionally allows you to suppress the action the double-click would trigger.

Search the event in the MSDN documentation for more information. You'll also find information there about how to work with application-level events, in case you're not familiar with them.